# Video Chat with Tor

Tags: chat

Is it possible to use a webcam with the Tor chat program to enable secure video chats? I have tried to find information on this topic, with no success so far.

Comment: Are you asking about OnionChat, Pidgin, TorChat or Xchat — or another chat app — in particular?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand Tor and the way it works you could use [Tortilla](http://www.crowdstrike.com/community-tools/) to route any type of traffic from any source through Tor.

Comment: Also OnionCat - https://www.onioncat.org/