# Is there a simple way to video chat over tor?

Tags: chat

Imagine a group of people with generally low/medium tech literacy. They have some ability to tech-support each other. Is there a simple-ish way for them to video chat with each other over tor?

I found this old answer but I don't know if it's still current, and since it didn't explain the steps I'm unsure if it would qualify as simple enough [Video Chat with Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3362/video-chat-with-tor)

The group members can be assumed to be able to install and use tor browser on a laptop/equivalent on a phone, or do something of similar complexity, but not much more.

There can be assumed to be one person able to set up e.g. a server, so some complexity could maybe be offloaded to that server/person.

The main blockers seem to be:

1. Tor browser doesn't allow camera nor mic access for websites (without extra configuration). I guess this is a big one.
2. Tor browser seems to block webrtc, which both jitsi and bigbluebutton seem to depend on.

And for what it's worth, is there ANY way to video chat over tor?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need a Tor browser to use browsing functionality over Tor. However - the user-unfriendly limitations in it **do have it's uses** for exact the target group of people you're mentioning - not tech experts. To do it securely you need a tech expert to help you to make a proper setup - I strongly recommend using virtualization. Either it will be a VirtualBox, or it will be QubesOS(more complex but a way more safer) - but you must use a proper insulation. Then you can utilize a regular browser routed through Tor and **only through it**, so no leaks will be taking place. The answer you've mentioned is just one of many possible solutions, but - generally - you need some software to make a virtual network among this group to make things run easily. After that you can use any video chat *inside that virtual private network* routed through Tor but **also** with a proper insulation on the user's computers. Find a skilled tech counselor to help you make the setup